# MySQL function with limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a MySQL function with input variable like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      SELECT Salary FROM (SELECT * FROM Employee
      ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT N-1, 1) AS tmp
  );
END
```

And it reports error. However, the following code works

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      # Write your MySQL query statement below.
      SELECT Salary FROM (SELECT * FROM Employee
      ORDER BY Salary DESC LIMIT N, 1) AS tmp
  );
END
```

Is there any way to achieve the goal that is to select the Nth highest salary with similar code? Thank you. (I am only allowed to change the content in the 'return' parentheses).

Comment: Is there a column for id?

Comment: You cannot use an expression in the limit clause, only integer literals.

Comment: Which version are you allowed to use?

Comment: which version of MySQL you are using?

Comment: There is not a column for id. And for the MySQL version I believe it is 5.7.21

Answer (score 1):

You can write something like this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION getNthHighestSalary(N INT) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
  RETURN (
      SELECT Salary FROM Employee e1
      WHERE N-1 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary) FROM Employee e2 
      WHERE e2.salary > e1.salary)
  );
END
```

Comment: This will not always work, when employees can have equal salaries.

Comment: You are right. @Hanqing Wu, what do you want to return when multiple employees have equal salaries?

Comment: This is not a problem of the question. If you want the 3rd salary from {10, 20, 20, 20, 40} - it will be 20. It doesn't matter that 20 is also on 2nd and 4th places. But your query will not return that.

Comment: Sorry that I am not very clear with the question. I believe Patel solved my problem. When there are multiple employees with the same salary, for example, the salaries are 1,2,2,2,2,3,3, then 2 will be the expected return for the second highest salary. Thank you all for your help.